# Confusion about checkbox-checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, checkbox, prop

I have somewhat around 100 courses with checkboxes that has class `course-chkbox` and I'm using the following code:

```
//Make sure user has checked at least one course        
if ($('.course-chkbox:checked').length === 0) {
    alert('You have to have at least one course selected');
    return false;
}
```

Is this correct based that I'm using the latest version of jQuery?

There are a lot suggestion of how to solve the same thing based on some googling...

```
     1. Usage of is("checked")
     2. Usage of prop()
     3. Looping through the elements involved and check each element if it's checked
```

What solution would be the best and why?

Comment: I think your current solution is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Considering performance wise your code is good than iteration.

> 1. Usage of is("checked")
> 2. Usage of prop()

These 2 cases has to undergo ***iteration***(looping through to check if it is checked).

```
$('.course-chkbox').is(':checked').length // returns undefined
$('.course-chkbox').prop('checked').length //returns undefined
```

In case if you try using *iteration*, then the code might look like (this can be reduced but this came up in my mind once I saw this post)

```
var tot;
$('.course-chkbox').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) { //or if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    tot = tot + 1;
  }
});

if (tot == 100) {
  alert('You have to have at least one course selected');
  return false;
}
```

So it is wise to go with your code.

```
if ($('.course-chkbox:checked').length) {
    alert('You have to have at least one course selected');
    return false;
}
```

I tried to create [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/length-vs-is-checked) for this testcase(Your code wins), not sure about the correctness of code.